# How to create a static IP for pods in OpenShift?

Tags: ip, kubernetes, openshift

I have an application that needs to get data from a mainframe using FTP.

Each MF account is connected to a specific IP, whenever I try to connect from the pod I am connecting through a different ip and therefore am unauthorized.

How can I connect the pod to a static IP in the OpenShift cloud environment?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to configure a [static egress ip for your project](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.14/networking/ovn_kubernetes_network_provider/configuring-egress-ips-ovn.html), but this typically requires cluster administrator privileges to set things up.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with OpenShift, although this is how it works in Kubernetes.

If you want your target pod to appear as if it had a static IP address, you can hide it behind service or ingress.

If you want your source pod to appear as if it had a static IP address, the short answer is you shouldn't rely on pod IP as pods are not expected to live forever and new one will likely end up with a different IP address assigned.

There are exceptions to that rule, though. Static pods defined using a yaml file in `/ect/kubernetes/manifests` on the Kubernetes node, as well as pods running as part of a `DaemonSet` will have IP address of the node they are running on. See sample IPs for pods running on Docker Desktop:

```
➜  ~ k get nodes -o wide
NAME             STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE         KERNEL-VERSION        CONTAINER-RUNTIME
docker-desktop   Ready    control-plane   40d   v1.27.2   192.168.65.4   <none>        Docker Desktop   5.15.49-linuxkit-pr   docker://24.0.2

➜  ~ k get pods -o wide -A
NAMESPACE       NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS         AGE   IP             NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-admission-create-9m9rc        0/1     Completed   0                33d   <none>         docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-admission-patch-9phx7         0/1     Completed   1                33d   <none>         docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-778d4c6454-v6mlt   1/1     Running     24 (2m49s ago)   33d   10.1.3.95      docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
kube-system     coredns-5d78c9869d-bqxn2                    1/1     Running     24 (2m49s ago)   33d   10.1.3.96      docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
kube-system     coredns-5d78c9869d-rxwqs                    1/1     Running     24 (2m49s ago)   33d   10.1.3.94      docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
kube-system     etcd-docker-desktop                         1/1     Running     88 (2m49s ago)   40d   192.168.65.4   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-apiserver-docker-desktop               1/1     Running     84 (2m49s ago)   40d   192.168.65.4   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-controller-manager-docker-desktop      1/1     Running     84 (2m49s ago)   40d   192.168.65.4   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-proxy-4lc7r                            1/1     Running     31 (2m49s ago)   40d   192.168.65.4   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-scheduler-docker-desktop               1/1     Running     67 (2m49s ago)   40d   192.168.65.4   docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
kube-system     metrics-server-5fb5598cf8-n5swd             1/1     Running     18 (2m49s ago)   24d   10.1.3.93      docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
kube-system     storage-provisioner                         1/1     Running     59 (2m11s ago)   40d   10.1.3.92      docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
kube-system     vpnkit-controller                           1/1     Running     31 (2m49s ago)   40d   10.1.3.91      docker-desktop   <none>           <none>
```

This obviously assumes the real source IP won't get hidden through NAT etc.